# How do you place the infowindow to the left or right side of a marker in GoogleMaps using Android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I was only able to find JavaScript codes to do this action. If anybody knows how to move the infowindow in Android studio, it will be of great help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to create a custom marker view on marker Click, than may be the below code will help you:

```
 private class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {


    private View v;

    MyInfoWindowAdapter() {
         //infowindow is your xml view class
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        // get the refrence of view and populate data

        return v;
    }




    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

}
```

Invoke the Above class on marker Click for eg:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

 MyInfoWindowAdapter myInfoWindowAdapter = new MyInfoWindowAdapter();

    mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(myInfoWindowAdapter);

    marker.showInfoWindow();
```